# How to reach JS variables in HTML table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a Javascript and html like below. All I want is to change the values bold areas with the "currMonth" and "currYear" variables' values, to make them dynamic. I appreciate for your help!.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
$(document).ready(function () {
var date = new Date();
var currMonth = date.getMonth();
var currYear= date.getFullYear();
currMonth +=1;
});
</script>


<html>
...
<table>
<td>...<td>
...
<td align="right" class="arrowIcon">
    <a href="index.php?m=**8**&y=**2015**&cat=0"><img src="images/rightarrow.gif" border="0"></a>
</td>
</table>
...
</html>
```

Thanks.

Edit: Thanks for the answers guys. All of them working!

Comment: Are you using jQuery? If so you could set the href attribute with the .attr(): http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In plain javascript, use `getElementById()` to fetch the anchor node, and `setAttribute()` to change the link. Example given [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k5yo7ef8/). But as you are using jQuery, it's easier to use the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function. Eg:

```
$('a').attr('href', 'index.php?m=' + currentMonth + '...');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can update href in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var date = new Date();
  var currMonth = date.getMonth();
  var currYear= date.getFullYear();
  currMonth +=1;

  $('table .arrowIcon>a').each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).attr('href', 'index.php?m='+currMonth+'&y='+currYear+'&cat=0')
  }
});
```

Comment: Best would be adding an identifier to the a-tag to prevent screwing up eventual future a's in the table

Answer (score 0):

you can get the href of the link and replace the ** ** placeholders with your variables like this:

```
var href= $('.arrowIcon).find('a').attr('href');

href = href.replace("**8**", currMonth);
href = href.replace("**2015**", currYear);
$('.arrowIcon').find('a').attr('href', href);
```

so, the other option to make it truly dynamic I would solve like this:

link html:

```
<a href="" data-cat="0"><img src="images/rightarrow.gif" border="0"></a>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var date = new Date();
  var currMonth = date.getMonth();
  var currYear= date.getFullYear();
  currMonth +=1;

  var cat= $('.arrowIcon).find('a').data('cat');
  $('.arrowIcon')
    .find('a')
      .attr('href',"index.php?m="+currMonth+"&y="+currYear+"&cat="+cat);

});
```

Comment: What if you want to update the date again with a new date? This way you'd have to re-edit this code each time you want to update

Comment: true, but I´m not sure if this is the case here. But yes, in this case i would rewrite the whole link. Maybe put the category var in some data-attribute so it wouldn´t be necessary to extract it from the href

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example that do not require jQuery if this is the only thing you are doing with javascript.

First of i moved the script tag to the buttom of the document to make sure that the html structure is created before the javascript is run. This is in general a good idea to not halt the rendering with javascript before the whole document is loaded, so placing the script tags in the bottom is best.

```
<html>
...
<table>
<td>...<td>
...
<td align="right" class="arrowIcon">
    <a href="index.php?m=**8**&y=**2015**&cat=0"><img src="images/rightarrow.gif" border="0"></a>
</td>
</table>
...

<script type="text/javascript">   
    var date = new Date();
    var currMonth = date.getMonth();
    var currYear= date.getFullYear();
    currMonth +=1;

    var atag = document.querySelector("table td a");
    atag.href = 'index.php?m='+currMonth+'&y='+currYear+'&cat=0';
</script>
</html>
```